# Separating Data in BOXPLOTPARAM (SAS GTL)

Tags: sas, sas-gtl

I have summarized data that I want to plot as box and whisker plots.  I have added an "outlier" point to certain classes.  I would like 2 separate plots, one with outliers and one without.

Here's what I've got:

```
data test;
input _stat_ $ _label_ $ col1 has_outlier;
datalines;
Max    A 2.1837546442 0
Mean   A 0            0
Median A 0.0101415946 0
Min    A -2.698021137 0
Q1     A -0.656874482 0
Q3     A 0.6635898047 0
Max    B 2.2346071965 1
Mean   B 0            1
Median B -0.025621533 1
Min    B -2.380132327 1
Q1     B -0.658781626 1
Q3     B 0.7248025307 1
Outlier B -2.120639115 1
Max    C 1.9904289904 0
Mean   C 0            0
Median C 0.0164299847 0
Min    C -2.032578831 0
Q1     C -0.454702942 0
Q3     C 0.7259160175 0
;



proc template;
  define statgraph boxplotparm1;
    begingraph;
      layout datapanel classvars=(has_outlier) / columns=2 rowdatarange=union;
          layout prototype / cycleattrs=true;
           boxplotparm x=_label_ y=col1 stat=_stat_ /
             datalabel=datalabel spread=true  dataskin=sheen outlierattrs=(color=red symbol=Asterisk);     
          endlayout;
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;
 
/* Generate the plot. */
proc sgrender data=test template=boxplotparm1;
run;
```

Producing this:
[image]

I would like to remove the classes from the charts where there is no box plot.  So the "No Outlier" group should only show "A" and "C" and the "Outlier" group should only show "B".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll get what you want with `COLUMNDATARANGE=UNION` which controls the X axis. `UNIONALL` is default and instructs it to have consistent X axes across all graphs; `UNION` instructs it not to.

You may not have a great looking graph if you go this route though, as it's going to be challenging to get the widths right I suspect.

```
proc template;
  define statgraph boxplotparm1;
    begingraph;
      layout datapanel classvars=(has_outlier) / columns=2 rowdatarange=union columndatarange=union;
          layout prototype / cycleattrs=true;
           boxplotparm x=_label_ y=col1 stat=_stat_ /
             datalabel=datalabel spread=true  
             dataskin=sheen outlierattrs=(color=red symbol=Asterisk)
             ;     
          endlayout;
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;
```

[image: Image of desired graph]

Comment: You should mention that `includemissinggroup=false` is also required on the `BOXPLOTPARM` statement.

Comment: @DomPazz Actually I don't think it is - I was playing around with that and forgot to take it out.